# Cutting bottom half of shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, pathfinder

I'm making a logo that currently looks like this:

[image]

But I actually want it to look more like this:

[image]

I've tried using Path Finder in Illustrator, but I'm not sure whether I'm doing something wrong or whether it's not suitable for what I'm trying to do.

I'm also trying to make the crescent shape fade out at the ends but can't seem to get it to work horizontally with the width profile.

The football, stars and crescent are all in their own layers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the first steps right.

You need to keep that oval shape you draw over your logo, select that circle **and go in the menu "Object" and select "Expand".**

That's probably what was missing. The pathfinder commands won't work with your thick stroke unless you convert it to a shape.

**Then do your Pathfinder:** Go on the Pathfinder panel, then select all, and you can use Divide (you can use trim too). Then you need to clean up what you don't need.

---

**Then for the 2 round shape at the ends of your new shape**, you can simply trace a perfect circle, and duplicate it at the other end as well.

[image: How to use pathfinder]

And then select all and do another Pathfinder + Divide... and delete the white parts you don't need.

[image: How to create curvy shapes using pathfinder]

**Is that the result you were hoping for?**

Make sure your circles from the previous step are well aligned or you might need to fix the end curves manually.

[image: Final result]

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to create a crescent that ends up in a very small point, you can simply draw your first oval using NO stroke and a black filling.

And then trace a bigger and wider oval in white, and put iton top of that black oval.

Adjust it as you prefer! Sometimes it looks nice if the white oval is a bit more on one side, it gives some kind of dimension to the crescent.

And then do the steps above with the Pathfinder and Divide (and then clean up.)

You can also use "Trim" instead of Divide and delete the bottom part of what was "cut".

[image: 2 ovals to create special crescent]

[image: 2 ovals to create special crescent adjustment]

**To delete the useless white and black oval parts,** a quick trick is to use the direct selection tool (white arrow), and trace a rectangle that will include the middle paths of that oval... then delete!

[image: How to erase half an oval]

You will still need to "clean up" your logo and remove the parts of the soccer ball that were cut.

When you "select all" your logo after all this, you should see something like this (your gradients will not look like this though):

[image: Cleaned up logo]

**Result:**

[image: Create a crescent in Illustrator]

---

**If you want a gradient**, you should do it in 2 separate steps... not directly as I explained above.

1A) Instead of using the oval with the stroke on the very first part of my answer, use a white filling oval. Duplicate it, you'll need it for step 2.

1B) Do your pathfinder + Divide on the logo.

2A) With the second oval, now add your thick stroke, do the "expand" command and then select that shape, and click "merge" on the pathfinder.

2B) Then you can "crop" again that oval in half, using a white rectangle or the 2 circles I mentioned above. And do another pathfinder + Divide on all this...

Then you can add a vertical gradient into this.

[image: Add gradient to shape]

Comment: Thanks @go-me. It is pretty much what I want to do. The only other thing is for the crescent line to fade out from the middle to the sides?

Comment: depending on version of illustrator, you should be able to simply use the gradient on the stroke.

Comment: @lauw0203 I edited my answer. Let me know if that's what you mean. If you want the ends to be white and have a gradient, use the gradient tool as you did for the soccer ball, but vertically.

Comment: @go-me the only problem I have now is when I save the image, the white circle overlapping the black one appears. Apart from that it's all working well :)

Comment: If you select it and delete it, will it work? You need to delete the parts you cut out with the pathfinder! Otherwise try selecting these parts and doing another divide. What I like to do to remove all the white after a "divide" is to trace a white square, select it, and then in the "select menu", I choose "select same fill and stroke"... then delete. And I do the same with a square with no filling and no stroke to remove all "invisible paths". Let me know if it works.

Comment: @go-me sorry, I wasn't doing it properly, that's right now. Only problem now is because I've ungrouped the objects, the ball lines are off.

Comment: @lauw0203 You should make sure you keep an original version of that logo (soccer ball) as it was before you started to remove the bottom part! And start again if you have to!

Answer (score 2):

OK, so you have an oval, here it has a white fill and an 8pt stroke:
[image]

Next go Object -> Path -> Outline stroke:
[image]

Now draw a line where you want to cut it:
[image]

And go Object -> Path -> Divide objects below:
[image]

This cuts the oval and its white background at that line.
Next right click and Ungroup those, and delete the bottom background and unwanted stroke: (background part greyed for visibility)
[image]

Lastly now you can apply a gradient fill to the black arc:
[image]